# Unexpected end-of-input exception from Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I do get a very strange exception in my online application, although very rarely, from Jackson. I still haven't figured out what the causes can be, as I stated before, it occurs extremely rarely.

There are similar posts in Stack Overflow about exceptions of this nature, but nothing about about `expecting closing '"'`

This is the stack trace:

```
TRACE - Fri Apr 10 11:22:52 BST 2015: ApsDataRetriever: Finished fetching Aps to populate the Aps screen with 0 aps returned
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing '"' for name
at Source: java.io.StringReader@7a55f3b4; line: 1, column: 4003703
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:454)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._parseFieldName2(ReaderBasedParser.java:1025)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._parseFieldName(ReaderBasedParser.java:1008)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:418)
..........
..........
```

This is a typical JSON object that is used in the application:

```
 {"xxxxxxxxIdentifier":{"xxxxxn":"XXX","xxxxxyNumber":"XXX/10247946","xxxxxactNumber":"T2/99833261","xxxxxxxxIdentifier":"XXX|XXX/10247946|T2/99833261","validxxxxxxxxIdentifier":true},"t2xxxxxxxxxxxeverity":"E","xxxxxei":"353705068167888","pxxxxxNumber":"XXX/10247946","contractNumber":"T2/99833261","xxxxxyHolderSurname":"Activatorius","policyHolderFirstName":"Forcilius","postcode":"W12 8RJ","vexxxxxReg":"J410H","xxxxxlexxxxxndModel":"Mercedes,SLK 500","postxxxxxVehiclexxxxxs":{"xxxxx":0.0,"distanceFromxxxxx":0.0,"xxxxxceFromxxxxxddress":0.0,"roadName":"","acceleration":0.0,"engineState":"UNKNOWN","xxxxxlexxxxxg":false,"dataOK":false},"eventNumber":"AL325","origin":"XXX","timestamp":1427466384000,"timestampclosed":0,"customerLastContactedTimestamp":0,"lat":51.34164810180664,"lon":-0.25955501198768616,"activeUser":"","timestampActiveUser":0,"assignedUser":"System","timestampAssignedUser":1427466384000,"xxxxxStatus":"COLLECTINGDATA","xxxxxType":"xxxxx","xxxxxHistory":[{"user":"T2","date":1427466864923,"detail":"xxxxx created"}],"xxxxxCustomerContactHistory":{"date":0,"contactReason":null,"contactOutcome":null},"maximumG":7.25,"speed":0.0,"notesList":[],"boxxxxxxId":"353705068167888|AL325","needMoreData":true,"needMoreDataAttempts":0,"boxInAnomaly":false,"crn":null,"pk":"AL325"}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the final JSON output

Comment: As it happened very rarely (the last time was a while ago and I was not able to debug it) I can't provide the actual JSON object in that specific circumstance

Comment: This sounds like you are consuming invalid JSON, specifically a field which does not properly escape a quote. You should try to catch this exception to print out the failing JSON.

Comment: You can try upgrading Jackson and see if it magically solves your problem. The JSON you have provided is valid JSON, so it is very odd that you are getting the error. I don't have much of a suggestion here, could try the [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) Jackson implementation in your project.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you were using Jackson 1.x version, so there is a possibility  that this could be a bug, if version is old (prior to 1.6 for example). At very least, I would upgrade to as recent 1.x as possible (latest patch for whatever minor version you area first; or maybe 1.9.13).

Otherwise this problem most likely comes due to something else in your system truncating input: for example, a server-side timeout in the middle of writing response could cause this (depending on how exception handling is done). Parser simply notes that in the middle of reading a field name, no more input is available, and throws exception.